# string to timestamp conversion plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, timestamp

I've inherited some data from an external source which is a `timestamp`. This was put into warehouse by someone as a `varchar2`. I need to convert this to a legitimate `timestamp` but am unsure how. This is how the string looks. "`2021-04-23T11:02:17.00Z`".

Would appreciate some help.

PS Ideally, I'd also like to know how to trunc this to a more traditional date format of `DD-MMM-YYYY` e.g. `21-Jan-2021` or even `DD-MM-YYYY` is fine.

Comment: One question per question (post) please. For your "PS" you should open another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `to_timestamp_tz()` to get the corresponding `timstamp with time zone`, convert it to the timezone you want it in (for example `sessiontimezone`) with `AT TIME ZONE` and `cast()` that to a `timestamp`.

```
SELECT cast(to_timestamp_tz('2021-04-23T11:02:17.00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF2:TZR') AT TIME ZONE sessiontimezone AS timestamp)
       FROM dual;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=23ee9cf5e475f05a4970321dcb329cba)

Comment: Really nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be too difficult. Extract the "date" part, apply `TO_DATE` function to it (with appropriate format mask) and - that's all. It means that you should "stop" at the `date_value` in the following query. The last, `final_result` is a string again, just formatted as you wanted.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '2021-04-23T11:02:17.00Z' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, 1, 10) string,
  4    --
  5    to_date(substr(col, 1, 10), 'yyyy-mm-dd') date_value,
  6    --
  7    to_char(to_date(substr(col, 1, 10), 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'dd-mm-yyyy') final_result
  8  from test;

STRING     DATE_VALUE FINAL_RESU
---------- ---------- ----------
2021-04-23 2021-04-23 23-04-2021

SQL>
```

---

In order to avoid that "operation", you might even create a **view**. For example:

This is a table you currently have:

```
SQL> create table test as
  2    (select 1 id, 'Littlefoot' name, '2021-04-23T11:02:17.00Z' col from dual);

Table created.
```

Create a view, re-using code I posted above:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_test as
  2    select id, name,
  3      to_date(substr(col, 1, 10), 'yyyy-mm-dd') col
  4  from test;

View created.
```

Select from it:

```
SQL> select * from v_test;

        ID NAME       COL
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Littlefoot 2021-04-23
```

Want another format? No problem:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mon-yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from v_test;

        ID NAME       COL
---------- ---------- -----------
         1 Littlefoot 23-apr-2021

SQL>
```

Or, apply `TO_CHAR` to view's `col` column (also demonstrated in code I posted first; see the `final_result`).

Comment: thank you for the guidance. It was actually simpler than I though and this worked:
to_date(substr(t.timestamp, 1, 10), 'yyyy-mm-dd') date_value

Comment: The trailing Z stands for zulu time (i.e. GMT/UTC) if I am not mistaken. Not sure if you don't want to take this into acount. I consider sticky bit's solution better, because the time zone is considered. From there you can still convert to a date or date string.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `TO_TIMESTAMP` function to do this.

Try:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-04-23T11:02:17.00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS')
```

You can read more about this function in their [Documentation](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_timestamp.php)

Comment: Sorry to see you got a downvote. The task is a little bit more complex than you thought, though. The T is not a valid part of a format string and you are ignoring the timezone. But your answer was at least close. See sticky bit's answer on how to convert this correctly.